# Check if variable with a number stored as contains a decimal point

Tags: php, strpos

I'm checking if a custom field has a decimal, and adding ".0" if it doesn't.

For some reason, I keep getting incorrect outputs: it adds a decimal either way.

```
function containsDecimal( $value ) {
if ( strpos( $value, "." ) !== false ) {
  echo "$value.0";
} else {
echo "$value"; }}
```

And the call:

```
<?php containsDecimal(the_field('carbs-g')); ?>
<?php containsDecimal(the_field('fiber-g')); ?>
```

With carbs-g = 1.2 and fiber-g = 0...

> This returns: 1.2.0 and 0.0

When I use this call I get the correct results:

```
<?php containsDecimal(1.2); ?>
<?php containsDecimal(0); ?>
```

> This returns: 1.2 and 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is backwards :-)

You are adding ".0" when the number already *has* a decimal (the strpos result *isn't* false). 
You should be adding it when strpos result *is* false (the number *doesn't* have a decimal).

```
function containsDecimal( $value ) {
    if ( strpos( $value, "." ) === false ) {
      echo "$value.0";
    } else {
    echo "$value"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an even better way to write it would be like this.  No reason to have === false.  You could also use get_field() instead, that might also help.

```
 function containsDecimal( $value ) {
    if ( strpos( $value, "." ) ) {
      echo "$value"; 
    } else {
        echo $value . ".0";
    }}
```

Comment: Is impossible to say that its "better", because we don't know how it fits into the rest of the OP's code. But it would work too, the important thing is that they fix their logic :-)